# No viable conversion std::weak_ptr to std::shared_ptr for method call

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I am able to convert back and forth inline.

```
std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook> mNotebook = ...;
std::weak_ptr<sfg::Notebook> weakNotebook(mNotebook);
std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook> strongNotebook(weakNotebook);
```

When I attempt to pass it to a method, I get the error:

```
"No viable conversion between std::weak_ptr<sfg::Notebook> to std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook>."
```

I am calling the method normally, and the method looks like:

```
onNotebookLeftClick(weakNotebook);

void onNotebookLeftClick(std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook> notebook) {
}
```

I am using OS X (10.10.2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`shared_ptr` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) you're trying to use is `explicit`.

```
template< class Y >
explicit shared_ptr( const std::weak_ptr<Y>& r );
```

Your first example

```
std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook> strongNotebook(weakNotebook);
```

works because you're using direct initialization, which works with `explicit` constructors. You'd have the same problem if you used copy initialization instead

```
std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook> strongNotebook = weakNotebook; // this will fail
```

---

To fix your error, do one of the following

```
onNotebookLeftClick(std::shared_ptr<sfg::Notebook>{weakNotebook});
```

or

```
onNotebookLeftClick(weakNotebook.lock());
```

Note that there's a difference between the two methods. If the `weak_ptr` has [`expired`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired), the first solution will throw `std::bad_weak_ptr`, while the second option will construct an empty `shared_ptr` in that case.